# How to remove all characters to the left of a character in a string

Tags: python, character

Here is on sample string:

NOMIGO* TATRA RR ER RR RR RA EEE E RR KH Dollars (U.S. $547,560.00

I am trying to remove "any" or random characters to the left of (U.S. (in Python) note the characters in this example are random and they will change. It needs to work with any characters present to the left of
(U.S
The number of characters could
also change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing

```
s = "NOMIGO* TATRA RR ER RR RR RA EEE E RR KH Dollars (U.S. $547,560.00"
s = s[s.find("(U.S."):]
print(s)
```

Output: (U.S. $547,560.00

Comment: `split` or `partition` would've been more readable.

Comment: Thank you, the text before the (U.S. will not constant it can change. I am looking for more of something that can remove "any" character before the (U.S.

Comment: Maybe `replace` would help? Sorry, but I'm still not sure what you mean by removing any character before (U.S.

Answer (score 0):

```
value = "NOMIGO* TATRA RR ER RR RR RA EEE E RR KH Dollars (U.S. $547,560.00"
```

split the value at `"U.S."` with `split_value = value.split("U.S.")`

This will split the string `value` into two sub-strings :

```
"NOMIGO* TATRA RR ER RR RR RA EEE E RR KH Dollars ("
```

and

```
" $547,560.00"
```

You want the second substring which is stored at index `1`

```
result = "U.S." + split_value[1]  # you probably also want the `"U.S."`, so we add it back
```

Comment: Would a wildcard work in your example this way any text can be removed?                value = "*."              Instead of 0

value = "NOMIGO* TATRA RR ER RR RR RA